# Adding EDNS options to DNS Server using scapy

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I want to add EDNS options to the DNS packets. I found EDNS, and EDNSOptions classes suggested on the internet to add the EDNS options, but these classes are not found in scapy.layers.dns. I need help with how to add ENDS options to the DNS response.

below is the code for the DNS server that I am using.

```
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.sendrecv import sendp, sniff
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSRR
import dns.edns
response = dns.message.Message()

from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP
# Set the interface to listen and respond on
net_interface = "Wi-Fi"


packet_filter = " and ".join([
    "udp dst port 53",          # Filter UDP port 53
    "udp[10] & 0x80 = 0",       # DNS queries only
    "dst host 192.168.9.0"    # IP source <ip>
    ])



def dns_reply(packet):

    # Construct the DNS packet
    # Construct the Ethernet header by looking at the sniffed packet
    eth = Ether(
        src=packet[Ether].dst,
        dst=packet[Ether].src
        )

    # Construct the IP header by looking at the sniffed packet
    ip = IP(
        src=packet[IP].dst,
        dst=packet[IP].src
        )

    # Construct the UDP header by looking at the sniffed packet
    udp = UDP(
        dport=packet[UDP].sport,
        sport=packet[UDP].dport
        )

    # Construct the DNS response by looking at the sniffed packet and manually
    dns = DNS(
        id=packet[DNS].id,
        qd=packet[DNS].qd,
        aa=1,
        rd=0,
        qr=1,
        qdcount=1,
        ancount=1,
        nscount=0,
        arcount=1,
        an=DNSRR(rrname='example.com', ttl=60, rdata='1.2.3.4'),

        ar=DNSRR(
            rrname=packet[DNS].qd.qname,
            type='OPT',  # set the resource record type to OPT for EDNS
            ttl=0,
            rclass=4096,  # set the rclass to 4096 to indicate the use of EDNS
            rdlen=None,

    ))
    # Put the full packet together
    response_packet = eth / ip / udp / dns
    # Send the DNS response
    sendp(response_packet, iface=net_interface)

# Sniff for a DNS query matching the 'packet_filter' and send a specially crafted reply
sniff(filter=packet_filter, prn=dns_reply, store=0, iface=net_interface, count=1)
```